# Android PercentRelativeLayout `aspectRatio` and Implicit Height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-percentrelativelayout

I would like to position one image on top of another while still preserving aspect ratio. Here's what I currently have.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <!-- 16 / 9 Image -->
        <ImageView
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_aspectRatio="178%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
            app:imageUrl="@{API.Backdrop(basePath, show)}" />

        <!-- 27/40 Aspect Ratio -->
        <ImageView
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_aspectRatio="67.5%"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:imageUrl="@{API.Poster(basePath, show)}"/>

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

This layout results in the second `ImageView` not rendering. It's probably caused by `PercentRelativeLayout`'s `layout_height` being `wrap_content` and the second `ImageView`'s height being based on the `PercentRelativeLayout`'s height.

What I want to happen:

- `PercentRelativeLayout` should take the height of the first `ImageView` (16/9).
- The second `ImageView` (27/40) gets its height from the `PercentRelativeLayout` (and indirectly from the first `ImageView`).
- The width of the second `ImageView` is calculated from its implicit height (including padding) and `app:layout_aspectRatio`.
- The second `ImageView` should overlap the left side of the first `ImageView`.

Here's a picture of what I want:

[image: relative layout example]